# USB-C wifi interference: VGA adapter recommendation (Macbook pro 2018)

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, vga-adapter

I just got a new MacBook Pro and bought this USB-C to VGA adapter to connect it to an external display ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B076X2XS9R/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1#customerReviews](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B076X2XS9R)).

Unfortunately, it created interferences with my wifi (precisely as described at http://osxdaily.com/2018/11/19/fix-macos-mojave-wifi-problems/) to the point that I could not connect anymore and had to give up on the adapter.

I suspect the quality of the adapter's shielding is mainly to blame. But maybe something else is also at fault: the Dell external display I use, the quality of the VGA cable itself, my desk and cables "spatial configuration"?

1. Has anyone else faced that problem?
2. How did you solve it? Does a higher quality adapter suffices, or is there something else I should consider?
3. If a better adapter does the job, what is the cheapest option you would recommend?